# How to hide a div with a script by clicking on a button

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to render invisible a div :
when the `.button-1` is 'active', the `.button-2` is hidden and vice versa.

*Something like `display:none` in CSS but using Javascript*

Script

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.button-1').click(function(){
        $(this).toggleClass('active');
    });
});

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.button-2').click(function(){
        $(this).toggleClass('active');
    });
});
```

Any idea ? Thanks.

Comment: So what is the problem? You can't hide the other button?

Comment: I want to hide .button-1 when .button-2 is actived, and to hide .button-2 when .button-1 is actived. I don't know how to do, maybe by giving IF / ELSE instructions in the script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you only want one of these items to be visible at a time?

You can set a up a "lock", so a variable with a state which represents which `div` is currently active.

So in your code (realistically you would place in a namespace somewhere, but just go get this working):

```
var activeButton = "button-1";

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.button-1').click(function(){
        $(this).toggleClass('active');
        if (activeButton == "button-2") {
            $('.button-2').toggleClass('active');
        }
        activeButton = "button-1";
    });
});

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.button-2').click(function(){
        $(this).toggleClass('active');
            if (activeButton == "button-1") {
               $('.button-2').toggleClass('active')
            }
            activeButton = "button-2";
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks @Viktor Chynarov, I edited your code, it seems to work, but there's something I didn't think about.. How to make reappear the .button-2 by clicking once again on the .button-1 ?

Comment: So button two should disappear after clicking on button 1, then after clicking on button one twice it reappears? I don't understand the intended behavior.

Comment: Something like this http://fiddle.jshell.net/ggw6hqsj/4/, you will find your code that I edited for the solution of my problem. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

You can use next script:

```
$('#button1').click(function(){
    toggleButtons();
});
$('#button2').click(function(){
    toggleButtons();
});

//hiding second button at the beginning
$('#button2').toggle();

//switch buttons visibility
function toggleButtons() {
    $('#button1').toggle();
    $('#button2').toggle();
}
```

See [Fiddle sample](http://fiddle.jshell.net/n0u0tqzt/).

Answer (score 0):

```
<style>
.button-1,.button-2 {
display: none;
}
.active {
display: block;
}
</style>
$('.button-1').click(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
    $('.button-2').toggleClass('active');
});
$('.button-2').click(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
    $('.button-1').toggleClass('active');
});
```

Without CSS:

```
$('.button-1').click(function(){
    $(this).toggle();
    $('.button-2').toggle();
});
$('.button-2').click(function(){
    $(this).toggle();
    $('.button-1').toggle();
});
```

Comment: You are on the right track but I don't think this is it.

Answer (score -1):

Could you use the following to set the CSS display to "none" using JQuery?:

```
$(this).css("display","none");
```

Answer (score -1):

if your div id is for example mydiv then you can use hide function in order to invisible it

```
$('#mydiv').hide();
```